# Serverless graphql split into micro services

Tags: amazon-web-services, lambda, graphql, serverless

How can i split my serverless graphql endpoint which runs in one lambda function into multiple micro lambda functions for scalability?
is it need to have multiple graphql end points ? or need to have only one graphql endpoint and resolvers split into seperate lambda functions ? what is the best architecture ?

Answer (score 2):

Usually, you access the entire GraphQL API with a single endpoint.

From [GraphQL.org](http://graphql.org/):

> GraphQL APIs are organized in terms of types and fields, not endpoints. Access the full capabilities of your data **from a single endpoint**. [emphasis added]

Of course, you could have multiple GraphQL APIs but those would be like separate services and your clients would need which one to access for which data.

You can have a single GraphQL endpoint and then dispatch some work to multiple Lambda functions but it doesn't necessarily need to be more scalable than a single function. Keep in mind that this single function will be run possible multiple times so having one function that does two things is not less scalable than two functions that do one thing each.

For example [How to write GraphQL Apps using AWS Lambda](https://cloudacademy.com/blog/how-to-write-graphql-apps-using-aws-lambda/)
on Cloud Academy recommends using a single AWS Lambda function for the entire API, using Express.

Maybe some other ways to build your service may be better suited to your needs, e.g. see [Designing a GraphQL API](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appsync/latest/devguide/designing-a-graphql-api.html) on [AWS AppSync Developer Guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appsync/latest/devguide/welcome.html).